# Cinnamon keyboard layout defaults to wrong layout

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I am running latest arch linux with Cinnamon as DE and upon boot the keyboard layout defaults to US. I want it to default to CZ. The system default keyboard is CZ - localectl outputs:

```
System Locale: LANG=cs_CZ.UTF8
VC Keymap: cz-lat2
X11 Layout: cz
```

I am guessing Cinnamon is overriding it. In the Cinnamon keyboard settings I have Czech layout **above** the US, but still after boot I get US.